# Colored terminal output ignores reset sequence. Color continues

Tags: bash, zsh, colors, gnome-terminal, iterm2

I fiddled with this for a couple of hours and couldn't find a solution...

Lets say I print this to a terminal *(tested with bash and zsh in a genome-terminal in a VM running a fresh Linux Mint)*:

```
python3
print("\033[41mFOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO\033[0m BAR")
```

- `\033[41m` enables a red background for the text that follows.
- `\033[0m` resets the background to the default.
- Assume that there are enough *O*'s to generate an output which fills exactly one and a half lines in the terminal.

In a fresh terminal the output looks like this (like I expected):

```
|FOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO|
|=================================|
|OOOOOOOOOOOOOO BAR               |
|==============                   |
|                                 |
```

- Every char that is underlined with a `=` has a red background.
- `|` Defines the border of the terminal.

So we see `FOO...` with a red background and `BAR` without a red background.

If I run the command again I get this:

```
|FOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO|
|=================================|
|OOOOOOOOOOOOOO BAR               |
|==============    ===============|
|                                 |
```

After `BAR` the line continues to be red... and I have no clue why? Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iTerm2 on Mac OS X also does this when the colored text wraps past the available columns. One workaround may be to erase to the end-of-the-line after writing `BAR` via the `CSI Ps K  Erase in Line (EL)` [control sequence](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html), e.g.

```
$ perl -e 'print "\e[41m".("a"x120)."\e[0mBAR\e[K"'
```

Comment: This does seem to work nicely when I replace `\e` with `\33`. Such a relief! Thanks :)

Comment: Many terminals do this.  It's the normal behaviour, when scrolling, of a terminal that implements _background colour erase_.  The new line scrolled up at the bottom of the scrolling area is erased with the current background colour.

Comment: @JdeBP, In the GNU `screen` terminal emulator, you can issue the `bce  off` command to turn off that behaviour.